# how to generate docker image Layer DiffID？

Tags: docker, docker-image

I read the Docker Image Specification v1.2.0.
It said:

> Layers are referenced by cryptographic hashes of their serialized representation. This is a SHA256 digest over the tar archive used to transport the layer, represented as a hexadecimal encoding of 256 bits, e.g., sha256:a9561eb1b190625c9adb5a9513e72c4dedafc1cb2d4c5236c9a6957ec7dfd5a9. Layers must be packed and unpacked reproducibly to avoid changing the layer ID, for example by using tar-split to save the tar headers. Note that the digest used as the layer ID is taken over an uncompressed version of the tar.

I want find out the specific process. So I try the flowing:

```
chao@manager-02:~/image_lab$ docker image save busybox:1.27-glibc > busybox.tar
chao@manager-02:~/image_lab$ tar -xvf busybox.tar 
47f54add1c481ac7754f9d022c2c420099a16e78faf85b4f2926a96ee40277fe/
47f54add1c481ac7754f9d022c2c420099a16e78faf85b4f2926a96ee40277fe/VERSION
47f54add1c481ac7754f9d022c2c420099a16e78faf85b4f2926a96ee40277fe/json
47f54add1c481ac7754f9d022c2c420099a16e78faf85b4f2926a96ee40277fe/layer.tar
fe2d514cd10652d0384abf2b051422722f9cdd7d189e661450cba8cd387a7bb8.json
manifest.json
repositories
chao@manager-02:~/image_lab$ ls
47f54add1c481ac7754f9d022c2c420099a16e78faf85b4f2926a96ee40277fe  Dockerfile                                                             manifest.json
busybox.tar                                                       fe2d514cd10652d0384abf2b051422722f9cdd7d189e661450cba8cd387a7bb8.json  repositories
chao@manager-02:~/image_lab$ sha256sum 47f54add1c481ac7754f9d022c2c420099a16e78faf85b4f2926a96ee40277fe/layer.tar 
545903a7a569bac2d6b75f18d399251cefb53e12af9f644f4d9e6e0d893095c8  47f54add1c481ac7754f9d022c2c420099a16e78faf85b4f2926a96ee40277fe/layer.tar
```

Why the sha256sum I generated is not equal to sha256sum of the image layer?

Comment: I've found [this](https://gist.github.com/aaronlehmann/b42a2eaf633fc949f93b#id-definitions-and-calculations) document. It seems `diffId` is computed from _uncompressed layer tar data_ .

Comment: I just used the uncompressed layer tar data.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you did answer your own question. This is what the [Docker image spec](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/image/spec/v1.2.md) says (as you quoted):

> [DiffID] is a SHA256 digest over the tar archive used to transport the layer (...)  Note that the digest used as the layer ID is taken over an uncompressed version of the tar.]"

But later on, when describing the content of the image, the same doc also says:

> There is a directory for each layer in the image. Each directory is named with a 64 character hex name that is deterministically generated from the layer information. *These names are not necessarily layer DiffIDs* or ChainIDs.

If you look at the `manifest.json` of your image, you'll see that the `rootfs.diff_ids` array points to same hash you obtained by `sha256sum`ing `layer.tar`. The hash you computed *is* the DiffID.

The obvious follow up question then is: *where did that directory name came from?!*

I am not sure, but [it seems](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/59e8ebd7f313753726c8de380f72300ed07b402e/image/tarexport/save.go#L314) that it is generated by whatever algorithm was used to generate layer IDs on the older Docker image format v1. Back then, images and layers were conflated into a single concept.

I'd guess they kept the v1 directory names unchanged to simplify the use old layers with newer Docker versions.

Footnote: AFAIU, the Docker image format spec is superseded by the OCI image format specification, but `docker image save` seems to generate archives in the older Docker format.)